# how to write text into Gmail Message Body by other browser

Tags: java, web-applications, gmail, message

I would like to do the following:

1. Open a web page → login gmail → compose mail
2. Open other web page →　Select a bookmark, open a java webapp(worked in tomcat)
3. The webapp will copy some text into the above Gmail's Message Body

●if the two pages are different tabs in same browser , is it possible?

●bookmark uses bookmarklet(javascript).

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: I dont know , it was an interview question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try formulating something like this

```
http://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=toaddress@domail.com&su=Subject&body=message&ui=1
```

and open it in a browser.

Comment: thank you.   but the question is how to do it in Gmail which has opened in step 1

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's at all possible. You're talking about completely different applications.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is possible without exploiting any browser security flaws. A web app opened in a browser shouldn't be able to interact with anything on your computer, and especially an other browser window.